# Does Python offer something like Perl's "unless"?

Tags: python

I have some code like:

```
if '@' in line and line == l:
    lineMatch = True
    line = line.strip('\n')
    line = line.split('@')[1]
    line = line + '<br>\n'
    labels.append(line)
```

I do not want to append a line to a label if it has `p4port` in it. Is there something like `unless` in Python, that would allow me to write something like `labels.append(line) unless 'p4port' in line`?

Comment: This question was, at some point, edited to replace the original question entirely with an unrelated debugging question that resulted from trying to apply the advice in a more complex context. The edit incorporated the solution for the original question. **Please do not do this**. New problems that come up are new questions; this is **not a discussion forum**, and such edits only confuse future readers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about 'not in'?:

```
if 'p4port' not in line:
    labels.append(line)
```

Also i guess that you code can be modified then to:

```
if '@' in line and line == l and 'p4port' not in line:
    lineMatch = True
    labels.append(line.strip('\n').split('@')[1] + '<br>\n')
```

Answer (score 15):

There's no "unless" statement, but you can always write:

```
if not some_condition:
    # do something
```

There's also the `not in` operator as Artsiom mentioned - so for your code, you'd write:

```
if '@' in line and line == l:
    lineMatch = True
    line = line.strip('\n')
    line = line.split('@')[1]
    line = line + '<br>\n'
    if 'p4port' not in line:
        labels.append(line)
```

... but Artsiom's version is better, unless you plan to do something with your modified `line` variable later.

Comment: how to modify my current if statement to do "if not in p4port" aswell without messing the current logic

Comment: Thanks, the trick to add `not` is great if we like the `unless` approach

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting in your (rather drastically) edited question is telling you that the variable `lineMatch` doesn't exist - which means the conditions you specified for setting it weren't met. It might help to add a line like `LineMatch = False` as the first line inside your outer `for` loop (before the first `if` statement), to ensure that it does exist.

Comment: The edits to the question were not appropriate, per how the site works; I rolled them back and then re-edited the original question for clarity.